# C++ Class Constructor Data Passing

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a quiz that’s due soon and I’m having a tough time with one question in particular. The question is:

**Implement the constructor for the class called "SimpleMath". The constructor takes two integer parameters; "var1" and "var2". The constructor is to store the value that was passed into "var1" into the private integer member variable "m_value1" and the value that was passed into "var2" into the private integer member variable "m_value2"**

This is my code;

```
class SimpleMath
{

public:

    SimpleMath(int var1, int var2);

    int getVar1() const
    {
        return m_value1;
    } 
    int getVar2() const
    {
        return m_value2;
    } 

private:
   int m_value1;
   int m_value2;

};
```

I was wondering if someone can verify that it is or is not correct. If it’s not I’d appreciate any help you can offer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Compile with Warnings enabled and Test the code by creating a few objects of the class SimpleMath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please implement the constructor in your example. 
Below example demonstrates how to do so:

```
class SimpleMath
{

public:

    SimpleMath(int var1, int var2) : m_value1(var1), m_value2(var2) {};

    int getVar1() const
    {
        return m_value1;
    } 
    int getVar2() const
    {
        return m_value2;
    } 

private:
   int m_value1;
   int m_value2;

};
```

Answer (score -2):

it's correct but you forgot to show how you store value, you juste define function here . . .

```
SimpleMath(int var1, int var2)
{
 //somme stuff
}
```

Comment: sry, was my nickname . . .

Comment: does not assign var1, var2 to class variables

Comment: of course, he don't want the whole solution. just if its correct or not corect

Comment: To help someone, make sure to check yourself properly, you may need more than the one you're helping.